# how to send push notification in ios from server using php in newer version of ios, without using pem file

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10

i have sent notification in older versions of ios. but in newer version i m not able to create .pem file. Someone told me that pem file is no longer required to send notification from server. But with bad luck i am not able to find any link regarding this. Someone please guide me how to send push notifications from server in newer version of ios.
I am stuck in sending notification since last week. Please help.
Here is the code i am using

```
private function pushnotification($deviceToken, $message, $type, $badge, $userid, $jobid) {
    $passphrase = '123456';

    $ctx = stream_context_create();

   // $file = base_path().  "/public/WenderCastPush.pem";
    //stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $file);
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'verify_peer_name', false);
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', true);
    //stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl','ciphers', 'TLSv1');
    // Open a connection to the APNS server
   // $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

    $body['aps'] = array(
        //'badge' => +1,
        'alert' => $message,
        'sound' => 'default',
        //'title' => $message,
        'type' => $type, 
        'userid' => $userid ,
        'jobid' => $jobid, 
    );
    // Encode the payload as JSON
    $payload = json_encode($body);


    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    if (!$result)
        $responce = 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
        $responce = 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

    // Close the connection to the server
    fclose($fp); 
    return $responce;
}
```

Comment: have u tried anything @Gaurav Malik

Comment: yes please question updated

Comment: Although you need not use Bluemix Push Notifications, you can use the Step 2 of the documentation to solve your problem https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/push_step_1.html#push_step_1 . The p12 certificate that's generated can be used with php script

Comment: Come on, 5 seconds of googling and first link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html which describes methods of authentication without certificate, alternate method with HTTP/2 and more...

Answer (score 4):

You can send notification using Firebase.
Your iOS app should be compiled with Firebase.
and call following address using Post method

[visit this link](https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send)

It is not very difficult.

check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVtIVfJJ35w).

Comment: there are other services also like onesignal --> https://onesignal.com/, it's free and has good documentation. REST API to send push is really easy

Answer (score 2):

Send push notifications to iOS using the new APNs HTTP/2 protocol with token-based (JWT with p8 private key) or certificate-based authentication

You Can use [This Package](https://github.com/edamov/pushok)

and documentation of [apple developers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html) its useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use iOS send notification with latest PHP version because, if your PHP code is not latest version, then notification send will not work.

```
if(defined('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0'))
{
    $device_token   = 'enter your device token';
    $pem_file       = 'enter your pem file path ;
    $pem_secret     = enter password';
    $apns_topic     = 'enter topic'; 


    $sample_alert = '{"aps":{"alert":"hi  yourporject name","sound":"default"}}';
    $url = "https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/$device_token";

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sample_alert);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("apns-topic: $apns_topic"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $pem_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $pem_secret);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

   

    var_dump($response);
    var_dump($httpcode);
}
```